# How to convert list of list to dictionary in Python?

Tags: python-2.7

I have the following list of list:

```
website=[["Ram"],["google"],["yahoo"],["linkedin"],["facebook"],["twitter"],  
    ["google"],["yahoo"],["linkedin"],["facebook"],["twitter"],["google"],["yahoo"],
    ["linkedin"]]
```

i would like to get the output like:

```
webdict={"Ram":1,"google":3,"yahoo":3,"linkedin":3,"facebook":2,"twitter":2}
```

Comment: Thanks to all for solving my problem. I am very novice to Python. I hope you guys helping out my programs in future also.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
website=[["Ram"],["google"],["yahoo"],["linkedin"],["facebook"],["twitter"],["google"],["yahoo"],["linkedin"],["facebook"],["twitter"],["google"],["yahoo"],["linkedin"]]

print dict([(i[0], website.count(i)) for i in website])
```

The output :

```
{'google': 3, 'twitter': 2, 'Ram': 1, 'yahoo': 3, 'linkedin': 3, 'facebook': 2}
```

To find out more about lists see the [doc](https://docs.python.org/2/tutorial/datastructures.html#more-on-lists)

- Section "5.1.4. List Comprehensions" will explain the `for` statement.
- Section "5.1. More on Lists" will explain the `website.count(i)`

Answer (score 0):

There is a class called [Counter](https://docs.python.org/2/library/collections.html#collections.Counter), which is designed for tasks like this. It's inherited from a dictionary, so just fill the items, and then print the result

```
website=[["Ram"],["google"],["yahoo"],["linkedin"],["facebook"],["twitter"],["google"],["yahoo"],["linkedin"],["facebook"],["twitter"],["google"],["yahoo"],["linkedin"]]

from collections import Counter
c = Counter()
for item in website:
    c[item[0]] += 1

print c
>>> Counter({'google': 3, 'yahoo': 3, 'linkedin': 3, 'twitter': 2, 'facebook': 2, 'Ram': 1})
```

Answer (score 0):

Since you want to count elements, easiest way is to use `collections.Counter` from standard library. Argument to `Counter` is a generator expression which retrieves first (only) element for each of list in `website` list.

```
from collections import Counter
website = [["Ram"],["google"],["yahoo"],["linkedin"],["facebook"],["twitter"],["google"],["yahoo"],["linkedin"],["facebook"],["twitter"],["google"],["yahoo"],["linkedin"]]
counter = Counter(o[0] for o in website)
# Counter({'google': 3, 'yahoo': 3, 'linkedin': 3, 'twitter': 2, 'facebook': 2, 'Ram': 1})
```